# Chart.js: Working with Version 2.7.2, but Facing 'Chart is not defined' Error in Version 4.4.1

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I'm attempting to create a chart using Chart.js. My current code is functional with version 2.7.2, but I intend to update it to version 4.4.1.

However, I'm encountering the following errors:

- xyz.js:722 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at chart.min.js:1:1)
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'helpers')
  at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:295
  at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:312

Previously, I used the following script tags for version 2.7.2:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
```

Now, I'm attempting to use the following tags for version 4.4.1:

```
<script
 type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
```

I've also moved the below code to a separate JS file.

```
const data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
```

Comment: Can you share how you are including chartjs 4.4.1 and the latest version of the plugin?

I noticed the latest version of chartjs-plugin-datalabels is 2.2.0, which is only one number different from the one you linked of 0.2.0
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js
vs
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these imports your code works:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js

```js
const data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" />
```

Comment: Why are you using 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
instead of 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.min.js"></script> ? 
Can you please explain what the difference is?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.min.js gives the error:

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module.

If you look at the file it has imports at the top. The other url doesn't use imports and works without any extra steps in the browser.

Comment: UMD, or Universal Module Definition, is a module definition format that aims to be compatible with both CommonJS and AMD. It also allows you to export the module as a global variable that you can include in your application through a simple <script> tag.

Comment: Im unable to display datalabels, did i add properly or im i missing something?
Below is my code
data: {
   labels: labels,
   datasets: [{
    data: values,
    backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(labels, reportColor[0]),
    datalabels: {
     color: 'white'
    },
   }]
  },
  options: {
   indexAxis: 'y',
   maintainAspectRatio: false,
   plugins: {
    datalabels: {
     color: 'pink',
     labels: {
      value: {},
      title: {
       color: 'white'
      }
     }
    },